# Setting up a condition in class-wc-countries.php for WooCommerce checkout (billing state)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to streamline and minimize the fields a customer has to fill out on the checkout page.
As an example: If a customer is from the UK the billing_state field named as 'County' pops up.
It's not required. So let's get rid of it.

I thought class-wc-countries.php is where you can find those conditions and rules. 
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-countries.php
It's in the WooCommerce - includes folder.

In lines 482pp (with germany as an example)

```
public function get_address_formats() {
    if ( empty( $this->address_formats ) ) {
        $this->address_formats = apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_localisation_address_formats',
            array(
                'default' => "{name}\n{company}\n{address_1}\n{address_2}\n{city}\n{state}\n{postcode}\n{country}",

                'DE'      => "{company}\n{name}\n{address_1}\n{address_2}\n{postcode} {city}\n{country}", [...]
```

So I tried to add

```
        'GB'      => "{company}\n{name}\n{address_1}\n{address_2}\n{postcode} {city}\n{country}",
```

no n{state}

This did not work unfortunately

Strangely there is the line for switzerland

```
            'CH'      => "{company}\n{name}\n{address_1}\n{address_2}\n{postcode} {city}\n{country}",
```

No state in the code but on the checkout the billing_state will show up.
I'm looking at the wrong place I guess.

In line 1262pp

```
                'GB' => array(
                    'postcode' => array(
                        'label' => __( 'Postcode', 'woocommerce' ),
                    ),
                    'state'    => array(
                        'label'    => __( 'County', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'required' => false,
```

OK, why not try to insert

```
                'state'    => array(
                    'label'    => __( 'County', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'required' => false,
                    'hidden'   => true,
```

Nope.

Can you point me in the right direction where this billing state condition/rule (dependend on from which country the user is) is set up?

Help is very much appreciated.